# Is there a command to get the HostNode CIDR ( not the podCIDR) kubectl or otherwise?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to find the network in which k8s worker nodes will be created. Is there a simple way to find it ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that k8s does not generally manage the node creation process ,  my only option seems to be using the k8s provider platform like pks , gcloud, az , aws to some how identify the subnet that the host-nodes will be dropped into.